# Windows software that display storage device using numbers and not letters

Tags: storage

Is there a software (in Windows) that can display storage devices (and its partitions) based on numbers and not letters?

From my understanding, Windows use `A:\` and `B:\` for floppy drive, `C:\` onwards for Hard disk (1 partitions for one letter), CD reader and writer drives, DVD reader and writer drives and using letters, we can only have a max of 26 drives / partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in Disk Management snap-in displays a diagram for each (numbered) disk featuring the partitions (not numbered but in numerical order.) You can launch the Disk Management snap-in by entering `diskmgmt.msc` into the Run dialog or start menu search field.

There can only be 26 *drive letters*, but since NTFS volumes can be mounted as a directory under another volume's drive letter (much like how volumes can be mounted anywhere in Unix) you can have many more than 26 logical volumes mounted while still using only the 26 available drive letters.

Comment: may I know how do you mount a NTFS volume (or partitions) as a directory (cause from my understanding, we mount disk volume as a letter and not a directory in the Windows context. However, in the Linux/Unix context, we can mount the volume as a directory.)? Does it also work for FAT32, FAT volume?

Comment: This [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307889) explains how to do it under Windows XP, and the same steps apply to all newer versions. It _may_ be possible to mount a FAT32 volume as a folder in an NTFS volume, but I don't have  a FAT32 volume to test with. FAT32 volumes, however, do not support mounting other volumes in their tree at all. NTFS includes numerous features which are aimed at matching the features of Unix, Linux, and Mac OS filesystems. From Mac OS, for example, we get multiple data streams; from *nix we get the ability to mount a partition anywhere in the tree.